# android apps aren't being stopped properly

Tags: android, updates, galaxy

I have a galaxy s8 and in the samsung my files app I see several folders in

Android\data\org.telegram.messenger\cache

date modified: mar 15, 2023 10:08 am

Android\data\org.telegram.messenger\acache
date modified: mar 15, 2023 2:33 am

Android\data\com.instagram.android\files\boomerang_frame_capture
date modified: mar 13, 2023 12:31 am
Android\data\com.instagram.android\files\copy_assets
date modified: mar 15, 2023 10:04 am

Android\data\com.microsoft.skydrive\cache
date modified: mar 15, 2023 10:22 am
Android\data\com.microsoft.skydrive\cache\current_log.txt
date modified: mar 15, 2023 10:22 am
Android\data\com.microsoft.skydrive\cache\logs
date modified: mar 15, 2023 9:22 am

There are several logs being produced every day sometimes twice a day for the past 5 days.

I have disabled permissions for these apps and disabled any storage access yet they still seem to add/update data in my phone. How can I stop these updates?

Comment: Apps don't need user permission to write to their own internal files/cache directories. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage. If you're unhappy about apps writing to these directories the best solution is to uninstall the app.

Comment: @KenWolf so there is no way to stop these apps from making logs and/or creating additional files or directories?